# Unable to mock ReactriveJWTDecoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Given I have the following custom implementation of ReactiveJwtDecoder:

```
@Component
public class CustomReactiveJWTDecoder implements ReactiveJwtDecoder
```

And I write a test like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AzureADConfigTest {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    private WebTestClient client;

    @MockBean
    AzureADService azureADService;

    @MockBean
    CustomReactiveJWTDecoder decoder;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Jwt jwt = createJwt();
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken user = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(new User("test@user.se", "", AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("A_AD")), "", AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("A_AD"));
        when(decoder.decode(anyString())).thenReturn(Mono.just(jwt));
        when(azureADService.getUserInfo(any())).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
        client = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void azureAdAccessGrated() {

        client
                .get()
                .uri("/api/userinfo")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + "token")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk();
    }

}
```

The mock is not respected. If I put a breakpoint inside my original impl that code gets executed instead of the mock.

My question is:
How can I mock a `ReactiveJWTDecoder` when im using a Spring Boot Security Resource Server? There are many suggestions on how to do it but none that I as simple as just creating a `@MockBean`.

Comment: Have you already tried comparing your solution to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/boot/oauth2resourceserver-webflux/src/test/java/sample/OAuth2ResourceServerControllerTests.java?

Comment: No i Will try that. What version are they using? I Dont have that fancy bilder pattern on JWT or mockJwt. Loots of new stuff in that.

Comment: That is the latest. But you should be able to just construct a `Jwt` with the constructor. I think the relevant test that mocks the decoder is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/boot/oauth2resourceserver-webflux/src/test/java/sample/OAuth2ResourceServerControllerTests.java#L99

Comment: That is what i have but im not using @WebFluxTest(OAuth2ResourceServerController.class)
@Import(SecurityConfig.class) as you can see. I Wonder if that is what Will make a Difference.